# Using differentials with volume of a cube

Tags: calculus, derivatives, volume, applications, area

My question is

The volume of a cube is increased from $1000$ cubic centimeters to $1156$ cubic centimeters.

Use differentials to determine. the side length of the cube increases by? the surface area increases by? and the surface area of the cube increases by what $\%$?

For, "how many centimeters does the side length increase by?" I did: 
$$v=x^3$$
$$\sqrt[3]{1000}=x$$
$$x=10cm$$

So $\sqrt[3]{1156}= 10.495cm$ now $ 10.495cm-10cm=0.495$ but the correct answer is $0.52cm$, what do I have to do differently.

For, "how many square cm does the SA increase?" I did:

$SA=6x^2$. plugged in $x$ for both the volumes and calculated the dif to be $60.88cm^2$ but the actual answer is $62.4cm^2$ 
and since I got that wrong the $\%$ increase was obviously wrong.
Any idea on what I should do differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a cube with side length $x$ and volume $V$, we have $x=V^{\frac13}$.

So $dx=\frac13 V^{-\frac23} dV$.

You would use the values of $V=1000$ and $dV=156$ to find $dx$.

Comment: oh okay thanks, but how would that work with SA. since if u differentiate it u get dSA=12xdx. what would be x?

Comment: You already had (in your question) that $x=10$ cm.

Comment: Or you could work with surface area ($A$) in terms of volume: $A=6\cdot V^{\frac23}$

Comment: so x would be same for volume and area? oh yeah it is the same.